# Fade effect for text summaries similar to Amazon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you look at a book, for example, in Amazon, you can see a rather nice (and much more intuitive than ellipses) effect for abbreviating text summaries:
[image]

Is there a well documented way of doing this or a library that facilitates such a summarization of text?

Comment: Did you look at the source code? As far as I can tell there isn't much magic going on there, it seems to be a div placed on top with a gradient and transparency.

Comment: That is a good point @Mahn. I was looking for a documented method of doing this for someone asking me the question, so I just defaulted to searching and hunting rather than digging into the source.  Simple enough!

Comment: That's okay, I think it's a good question either way, just wanted to point that out for information purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The extra content is hidden from view with these rules: `height: 200px;` and `overflow: hidden;`; you can see them applied to `#outer_postBodyPS`.  But the fade effect is handled in `#psGradient`:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255, 255, 255) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100% );
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, bottom, top, color-stop(15%, rgb(255, 255, 255)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)) );
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100% );
background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100% );
background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100% ); 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#03ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0 ); 
background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255, 255, 255) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100% );
```

The different prefixed rules (and the filter) are just for browser-specific instances.

You can inspect the whole stylesheet with these rules at [http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/browser-scripts/dpMergedOverallCSS/dpMergedOverallCSS-12049068973.*V1*.css](http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/browser-scripts/dpMergedOverallCSS/dpMergedOverallCSS-12049068973._V1_.css).

Answer (score 0):

The visual effect is simply CSS. There's a div with a gradient image fixed to the bottom which adds a "fade" illusion. Set the overlay to `position:fixed;bottom:0` to add that visual effect.

As far as actually truncating the text, there are many ways to do it. The easiest way is to use the substring functions, like PHP's substr. http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php and simply cut off after X characters.

Alternatively, you can explode http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php the string on the [space] character and that would return an array of words. You can then iterate through that array easily and stop when you reach X words...